# Looking for a way to make a hover animation that changes color instantly but goes back to the old color slowly

Tags: css

Example that I've seen before: https://steamtimeidler.com/

see when you hover the button it changes the color instantly but when you move the cursor away it fades to the old color slowly

I have no idea how to go about doing this, does anyone know how?

Comment: You just need to add `ease-in-out` value in transition property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the :not selector on the :hover selector it self, so you start aplying the transition rule only after you already hovered the element

The CSS

```
button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #9ccc65;
  border:none;
}
button:not( :hover ) {
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
button:hover {
  background: #fbc02d;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<button>Hi There</button>
```

And a working example
https://codepen.io/Teobis/pen/jKzwVj

Comment: Mark the answer like a charm please :)

Answer (score 1):

CSS onomouseout:

```
div:not( :hover ){ transition }
```

CSS onmouseover:

```
div:hover{ color }
```